# Execute dotnet command with Process in C#

Tags: c#

I have following C# lines of code where open process and run dotnet command to open my console application (created with .net standard/core)

```
var args = new Dictionary<string, string> {
 { "-p", "title"},
 { "-l", "games"},
 ...
};

var arguments = string.Join(" ", args.Select((k) => string.Format("{0} {1}", k.Key, "\"" + k.Value + "\"")));

var dllPath = @"C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\myConsole\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\myConsole.dll";
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
procStartInfo.FileName = "C:\....\cmd.exe";
procStartInfo.Arguments = $"dotnet \"{dllPath}\" {arguments}";
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Process pr = new Process();
pr.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

pr.OutputDataReceived += (s, ev) =>
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ev.Data))
    {
        return;
    }

    string[] split = ev.Data.Split(new char[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    int.TryParse(split[split.Length - 1], out output);
};

pr.ErrorDataReceived += (s, err) =>
{
    // do stuff here
};

pr.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
pr.Start();
pr.BeginOutputReadLine();
pr.BeginErrorReadLine();

pr.WaitForExit();
```

The command `Arguments` result is:

```
dotnet "C:\Users\xyz\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\myConsole\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\myConsole.dll" -p "title" -l "games" -s "" -r "none" -k "0" -d "/path/" -f ""
```

But for `ev.Data` from `OutputDataReceived` event looks like:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.665]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

and that's all...

I expected to run dotnet command to dll.

If I run manually the result command `dotnet ....` above, works fine. But not from my C# code. Why ?

Comment: Just a guess, but perhaps because you run the cmd command. Is it not possible to run the dotnet command immediately?

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Threads, decent odds you can see why one of the event handlers deadlocked.  ErrorDataReceived, probably.

Comment: I put breakpoint in `ErrorDataReceived` and never reached

Comment: Yes, I'm sure ... The complete url: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe`

Comment: And why not procStartInfo.FileName = "dotnet.exe"?

Comment: Nice, it works ! Propose it as answer and I will mark it. `dotnet` is enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because cmd returns:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.665] 
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

You need to call

```
procStartInfo.FileName = "dotnet"
```