# How to run "dotnet myDll.dll" from a .net core project?

Tags: c#, linux, macos, .net-core

I have a .net core project on mac/linux, which I can run from the terminal using

```
         dotnet myDll.dll
```

I want to run this from my c# project code - so start up the webapp and then run ui tests against it.

I have tried

```
        var path = "path-to-my-dll/myDll.dll");

        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path, "")
        {
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path)
        };

        var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

However this just runs the terminal equivalent of

```
        ./myDll.dll
```

How do I call the dotnet command?

Comment: Have you tried setting the path to `dotnet` and passing `myDll.dll` as first argument in the `ProcessStartInfo`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to huysentruitw and [Execute dotnet command with Process in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474306/execute-dotnet-command-with-process-in-c-sharp)

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(expected, "")
        {
            FileName = "dotnet",
            Arguments = "myDll.dll",
            WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path)
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass `dotnet` as a `fileName` and `myDll.dll` as the startup argument to the [`ProcessStartInfo` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_ProcessStartInfo__ctor_System_String_System_String_), like this:

```cs
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("dotnet", "myDll.dll")
{
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path),
};

var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```